# Javascript event functions question

Tags: javascript, events

Why when I add an event as a function like this:

```
function func(arg) 
{
arg.style.marginLeft = "65px";
}
window.onload = function() {
var test = document.getElementById("aaa");
test.onmouseover = func(test);
}
```

It's been executed immediately (even if I do not hover the element).

But this one works:

```
window.onload = function() {
var test = document.getElementById("aaa");
test.onmouseover = function() {
           test.style.marginLeft = "65px";
      }
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: assigning directly to `onload` and `onmouseover` is kind of brittle.  If you or any other code ever want to add a second handler, the first one is lost.  Consider using `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` in IE), or using a library like jQuery which handwaves the problems away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the "onmouseover" property to the return value of a **function call expression**:

```
test.onmouseover = func(test);
```

That "func(test)" calls the function "func()", just as it would in any other code.

You could instead do this:

```
test.onmouseover = func;
```

That will bind the event handler and not call "func()", but it won't arrange for the additional parameter to be passed. *edit* Oh wait that's just the DOM element itself.